# Scala How to match two list to a Map or tuple

Tags: list, scala, dictionary, tuples

```
val listA = List("one", "two", "three")

val listB = List(1, 3, 4, 9, 2, 6)
```

Result:

```
val m: Map[String, Int] = Map(one -> 1, two -> 2, three -> 3)
```

I want to pair `listA` and `listB` to a `Map` with corresponding key/value. I have tried to use the `zip` method but it only support sequential merging. How can I achieve the above result?

Answer (score 1):

If `f(x)` is a function that can return the corresponding numerical value for the given alphabetical value, you can just map each `x` in `listA` to a pair `(x, f(x))` and then turn the resulting list of pairs into a map using `.toMap`.

Comment: This doesn't filter for f(x) in listB.

Answer (score 1):

`zip` with `sorted` listB:

```
listA.zip(listB.sorted).toMap
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. How about if both lists are not numerical value? Let's say listA = ("sheep", "cat", "dog"), listB = ("puppy", "kitten", "lamb")

Answer (score 0):

Do you intend:

```
scala> val listA = List("one", "two", "three", "four")
listA: List[String] = List(one, two, three, four)

scala> val listB = List(1, 3, 4, 9, 2, 6)
listB: List[Int] = List(1, 3, 4, 9, 2, 6)

scala> val m = Map("one"->1, "two"->20, "three"->3)
m: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,Int] = Map(one -> 1, two -> 20, three -> 3)

scala> listA flatMap { case k if (m contains k) && (listB contains m(k)) => Some(k, m(k)) ; case _ => None }
res4: List[(String, Int)] = List((one,1), (three,3))
```